# RNFirebase core module was not found natively on ios

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification

Estoy desarrollando una app para **iOS**.
Después de hacer toda la instalación de `firebase`, `PushNotifications` y todas las configuraciones en `XCode`, al darle **Run** desde Xcode la aplicación funciona bien, me pide permiso para habilitar las notificaciones y no hay ningún problema. Pero si le doy `react-native run-ios` desde **VisualStudio** me tira el siguiente error

> RNFirebase core module was not found natively on ios

Me esta volviendo loco, gracias =)

Answer (score -1):

Seria bueno que escribieras la versión de react native la cual estas utilizando, teniendo en cuenta que la versión 0.60 cambio bastante la forma de implementar librerías nativas.

Normalmente con el comando " react-native link nombre-libreria-firebase ", se debería arreglar sin embargo a veces falla y toca ajustar manualmente con las opciones que brinda Xcode.

El siguiente link explica como importar de forma manual en caso de que con react-native link falle la importación https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios